# How to get current line of source file when processing a macro?

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to pre-process C source code with jinja2 and I would like for some macros to be able to output `#line` lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from jinja2 import *
@pass_context
def mymacro(ctx):
    return '#line ?? "??"'
env = Environment()
env.globals["mymacro"] = mymacro
rr = env.from_string(
    """
// file.h
{{ mymacro() }}
"""
).render()
print(rr)
```

How do I get current line within `mymacro` global? I tried inspecting `jinja2.runtime.Context`, but I can't find anything helpful. Is this possible? Note that the line of macro invocation is visible when an exception is thrown - so it is stored somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line that brought a solution:

> ```
> template = tb.tb_frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__")
> ```

*<sup>Source: [debug.py#L55](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/a42b291bf2a3ac69f978ee88418ca6d0c7879d1e/src/jinja2/debug.py#L55)</sup>*
The variable `tb` being a exception traceback, in this context.

And then, looking further, I realised that Jinja is using this line [`__jinja_template__` to frame where the template lines are in the stack of Python](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/bb7f3a51091d91010deb1e01e69f4f255d3b3eb6/src/jinja2/environment.py#L1255).

With that, and the function [`get_corresponding_lineno`](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/a42b291bf2a3ac69f978ee88418ca6d0c7879d1e/src/jinja2/environment.py#L1464) that they are using a few lines later in the *debug.py* file:

> ```py
> template = tb.tb_frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__")
>
> if template is not None:
>     lineno = template.get_corresponding_lineno(tb.tb_lineno)
> ```

*<sup>Source: [debug.py#L58](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/a42b291bf2a3ac69f978ee88418ca6d0c7879d1e/src/jinja2/debug.py#L58)</sup>*

It was now quite clear how to achieve it:

- get the whole Python stack
- loop over it until you find the template boundary
- translate the current line of Python code in a line of the template with the help of `get_corresponding_lineno`

This gives:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from jinja2 import *
from inspect import stack, currentframe

def mymacro():
    for frameInfo in stack():
        if frameInfo.frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__") is not None:
            template = frameInfo.frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__")
            break
    return (
        '#line '
        f'{template.get_corresponding_lineno(currentframe().f_back.f_lineno)}'
    )
    
env = Environment()
env.globals["mymacro"] = mymacro

rr = env.from_string(
"""
// file.h

{{ mymacro() }}
"""
).render()

print(rr)
```

Which prints us:

```
// file.h

#line 4
```