# How to get the calling code for a filter in jinja

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

**tl;dr**: is it possible to find out where in a jinja template calls a jinja filter from within the filter?

### Background

So I have a filter that I'm using in a jinja template called `get_image_path()`, essentially it takes in a file path and/or url and puts it into the proper format for the app.

I am trying to format traceback outputs so that I can get some idea where they are coming from if someone has an error. Basically when someone passes something that isn't a usable path I want to be able to throw an error and provide a message with the line in the template that called the filter so people know which variable to look for.

So is it possible for me to get the line **in the template** that called the filter, or do I have to do manual traceback formatting?

Current code for `get_image_path()`

```py
def get_image_path(path:str) -> str:
    # I omitted the docstring
    try:
        if path.startswith("http"):
            return path

        elif path.startswith("images"):
            return f"{path}"

        else:
            return f"images/{path}"
    except AttributeError as e:
        traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__, limit=7)
        ValueError(f"ValueError: Could not get image path: {path}")
```

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784095/how-to-get-current-line-of-source-file-when-processing-a-macro (didn't check if that applies to filter, but I guess it could).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for your comment this was driving me nuts, I just posted an answer I found using the information from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My solution

For me the issue is caused by an `AttributeError`:

```py
def get_image_path(path:str) -> str:
    try:
        if path.startswith("http"):
            return path

        elif path.startswith("images"):
            return f"{path}"

        else:
            return f"images/{path}"
    except AttributeError:
        for frameInfo in stack(): # Get the frame for the error raised
            if frameInfo.frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__") is not None: # Find the jinja template namespace if it exists
                template = frameInfo.frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__")
                break
        if not path: # If the image path is False (usually because a required image wasn't provided)
            raise ValueError(f"\n\nNo path provided for required image in {template.filename} #line {template.get_corresponding_lineno(currentframe().f_back.f_lineno)}")
        else: # If it's just an invalid image path
            raise ValueError(f"\n\nCould not get image path: {path}\n Error occured on \n{template.filename} #line {template.get_corresponding_lineno(currentframe().f_back.f_lineno)}")
```

When the filter fails because a `boolean` is passed instead of an image path this message is now provided:

> ValueError:
> No path provided for required image in
> c:\users\kieran\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\ezcv\themes\ethereal\index.jinja
> #line 45

### Background & How it works

So when in the except statement these lines:

```py
for frameInfo in stack(): # Get the frame for the error raised
            if frameInfo.frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__") is not None: # Find the jinja template namespace if it exists
                template = frameInfo.frame.f_globals.get("__jinja_template__")
                break
```

are using the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to check if a value in the global namespace called `__jinja_template__` is found. If this value is found it means the error was raised in a template and from that we can get the Jinja [Template Object](https://tedboy.github.io/jinja2/generated/generated/jinja2.environment.Template.html#jinja2.Template). This object contains the info about the line number and filename I want so it gets assigned to the `template` variable.

From there `template.filename` will give you the source file path, and `template.get_corresponding_lineno(currentframe().f_back.f_lineno)` (documentation [here](https://tedboy.github.io/jinja2/_modules/jinja2/environment.html#Template.get_corresponding_lineno)) will give you the line number, and the rest of the code is just formatting the `ValueError` to pass the information I want back to the user.

Thanks to @β.εηοιτ.βε for the suggestion of looking at their answer to [How to get current line of source file when processing a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784095/how-to-get-current-line-of-source-file-when-processing-a-macro) to figure all this out